# Beginner needing help to create simple documentclass for traditional printed Tibetan manuscripts (Pecha)

Tags: positioning, printing, documentclass-writing

[image: Tibetan Pecha]

I am delighted to see how well XeLaTeX can handle Tibetan script and want to use it for the typesetting engine for my software.

The first thing I want to do is to create a simple documentclass, with the certain rules I shall describe below. I have included a picture with colour coded rectangles to show what I need to do.

- First of all I need each page of the document properly aligned so that for an A4/legal sized paper page, the text boxes are printed on the exact place on both sides of the paper. The back side of the paper needs to be flipped upside down, since traditional Tibetan manuscripts are turned on the horizontal axis, whereas Western books are turned on the vertical axis. For A4/legal size paper, there should be a single Tibetan page centered on each side of the paper, but an A3 sized paper should have two Tibetan pages on each side of the paper sheet in order to not waste paper.
- the pages must be in landscape orientation.
- Each Tibetan page should have three text boxes as one can see on the image: The box to the far left (yellow and purple) is rotated 90 degree clockwise, but the one to the far right (orange) is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise.
- The text box marked with purple is the title of the manuscript and should be printed on every even numbered page.
- The text box marked with red, shows some characters that can be represented with Unicode and should be printed on every odd numbered page as well as on title pages. It should be followed by a long blank space, marked by the blue rectangle.
- Each stanza is normally marked with vertical lines. These lines have spaces in between them (green rectangle), but these spaces can vary in length depending on certain circumstances. Looking at the light blue rectangles on both the top page and the bottom page, the top one is a bit shorter due to the line breaking. This word consists of two columns, while the word marked by the bottom light blue rectangle only has one column, hence allowing a full length space between the vertical bars separating the stanzas.

I mainly need your help to learn how to create the framed text boxes that have a fixed position on the printed page, with the text box on the backside of the paper sheet being printed upside down. However, any other tips with regards to what I'm trying to accomplish is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Creating a new document class is more work than you need, especially for a beginner.  The easiest way to reuse formatting commands is to put them into a separate .tex file and use \input in the preamble (before \begin{document}).  Also, check out the flowfram package.

Comment: How can I make it so that my document starts with one page of a certain environment, like the example you provided in your answer, but then have other environment for the rest of the document? Your example below is only supposed to be used for the title page, so I need to be able to switch environments depending on the context. How is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can specify the page or range of pages for each frame.  So you need one set of frames for page 1, another set of frames for page 2, and a third set of frames for the remaining pages.

Comment: If you mean the contents of the dynamic frame which appear on the left and right sides, you can use macros (like \thepage).  Every time you want to change the contents, change the macro definition.  IIRC, changes will not appear until the next page.

Comment: Oops, changes are implemented on the same page.

Comment: I have realized that I need to fit multiple environments on a single sheet of paper. I have described the problem in detail in another question, since it technically is a bit different: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185660/printing-multiple-non-standard-sized-document-pages-on-two-sides-of-one-piece-of

Comment: I ASKED if you wanted help the the other pages!  You seemed to want to do it yourself.

Comment: Pardon me. I didn't see your kind offer. I would really love to get some help, as I am very new to LaTeX and feel very overwhelmed by the complexity.

Comment: This is all very much possible with TeX, and no you don't need to insert page breaks manually. I just answered a [similar question earlier today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207031/typesetting-devanagari-manuscript-style-pothi-patravali-books) and this is not much harder to do either. I also just now noticed there exists a [package called `pecha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pecha). I can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, you are going to have to manually add page breaks.  I have added a few commands to help.  \pagepar is used to break a page between paragraphs, and \pagenopar to break a page in the middle of a paragraph.  Both accept a character or box to place in the lower right corner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\geometry{paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\yigobox}{\noindent\makebox[2.11cm][l]{yigo}}

\newcommand{\pagepar}[1]% #1 = character or box at end
{\ifvmode\vfill\fi\hfill{#1}\newpage}

\newcommand{\pagenopar}[1]% #1 = character or box at end
{#1\parfillskip=0pt\newpage\parfillskip=0pt plus1fil\noindent}

\newdynamicframe[1]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[title]
\setdynamiccontents*{title}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black!60!red]
  (0,0) (29.7,7)%bounding box
  (5.7,1.93) rectangle +(18.3,3.14)
  (5.77,2) rectangle +(18.16,3)
  (6.2,2.43) rectangle +(17.3,2.14)
  (6.27,2.5) rectangle +(17.16,2)
  (7.67,2.5) rectangle +(.07,2)
  (8.27,2.5) rectangle +(.07,2)
  (21.47,2.5) rectangle +(.07,2)
  (21.97,2.5) rectangle +(.07,2);
\node[rotate=90] at (6.97,3.5) {\leftside};
\node[rotate=-90] at (22.67,3.5) {\rightside};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newdynamicframe[2]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[image]
\setdynamiccontents*{image}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black]
  (0,0) (29.7,7)%bounding box
  (2.63,1.06) rectangle +(24.1,4.94)
  (2.7,1.13) rectangle +(23.96,4.8)
  (3.2,1.63) rectangle +(22.9,3.74)
  (3.27,1.7) rectangle +(22.76,3.6)
  (4.5,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (5,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (12.38,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (12.94,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (16.24,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (16.8,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (24.3,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6)
  (24.8,1.7) rectangle +(.07,3.6);
\node at (14.625,3.5) {\image};% max width=3.2cm, max height=3.6cm
\node[rotate=90] at (3.92,3.5) {\leftside};
\node[rotate=-90] at (25.45,3.5) {\rightside};
\end{tikzpicture}}
% set up text flow arround image
\def\textflowimage{\shapepar[1cm]{{9.5}% text flow arround image
{0} b{0} b{11.8}\\
{0} t{0}{7} t{11.8}{7.1} \\
{3.6} t{0}{7} t{11.8}{7.1} \\
{3.6} e{7} e{18.9}}}

\newdynamicframe[3-100]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[standard]
\setdynamiccontents*{standard}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black]
  (0,0) (29.7,7)%bounding box
  (2.63,1.18) rectangle +(24.1,4.64)
  (3.43,1.18) rectangle +(22.5,4.64);
\node[above,inner sep=0] at (14.85,6.1) {\header};
\node[rotate=90] at (3.03,3.5) {\leftside};
\node[rotate=-90] at (26.33,3.5) {\rightside};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newflowframe[1]{12.7cm}{1.5cm}{8.5cm}{2.6cm}
\newflowframe[2]{18.9cm}{3.5cm}{5.3cm}{1.7cm}
\newflowframe[3-100]{22.3cm}{4.3cm}{3.5cm}{1.4cm}

\def\imageH{3.6cm}% max height of image
\def\imageW{3.2cm}% max width of image

\def\leftside{}% default
\def\rightside{}% default
\def\image{}% default
\def\header{}% default

\begin{document}
\Large
\def\leftside{left side \thepage}
\def\rightside{right side \thepage}
\noindent Title page.
\newpage
\def\image{\includegraphics[width=\imageW,height=\imageH]{image}}
\textflowimage\yigobox
This is a test of the ability to flow text around the image in the center of this page.
\newpage
\def\header{header}
\yigobox
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habi-
tant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum
urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget
sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. 
\pagenopar{}Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec
varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
\end{document}
```

[image: title]
[image]
[image: standard]
[image: page break]

I assume page 2 is printed on the back of the title page, otherwise I'll need to add some blank pages.

Comment: This looks really great and I am very thankful for this. Do you know how to get every even sided page flipped upside down?

Comment: Are you sure you need to?  Try printing all 4 pages on your printer (landscape) and see if the flip over correctly.

Comment: BTW, do you want help with the other pages (see http://digitaltibetan.org/index.php/How_to_create_an_LibreOffice_pecha_template).

Comment: Do you know why the printing is done correctly even though my PDF reader displays everything in the same orientation?

Comment: Have you ever seen 2 sided documents printed in landscape?   Every other page is printed upside down.  It has to do with left-right becoming up-down.

Comment: So obvious when you think about it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused about features like yigo.  The instruction place it off to the right, but the example shows it inside the text area.  If it can be placed in the text flow (as a box), it is easier to do so.  If it has to be placed at a specific location on the page and have text flow around it, big trouble!

Comment: Manually adding page breaks doesn't seem like a very elegant solution. What happens if I add text in between page breaks? Then I have to move the page breaks and do several renders in order to get everything looking good. Then I have to repeat the process every time I modify the text. Is there no way to solve this? Perhaps a document class is required?

Answer (score 1):

I've add automatic dBu aKhyud ༄༅ insertion ability to XeTeX to make typesetting Tibetan classic long book easier, finished about 9 years ago. Executables for Cygwin64 & Linux and some typesetting examples are available at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NHzc5VM1ZYwj1iLSfXndNxeOmb3SGNKO?usp=sharing, Together with a tibclassic.tex package, available at https://gitee.com/gendun-jiangcuo/tibexpkg.git. Sorry most of the documents are in Chinese. It is available at https://gitee.com/gendun-jiangcuo/tibexweb.git. Give it a try if you have lots of pages to typeset. Here's a example, sorry for the nasty hacking code, cause I do not know TeX programming very well. The comments are in Chinese, Google translate may helps.

```
\input tibclassic %排版藏文長函書的庫
\input colordvi %彩色文字，說明見dvips.pdf
%
\setpaperhalfa4%將紙張設爲半張A4大小
\DontSplitDblShad%將།།排成兩個།緊挨着，在後面留空的風格，གཉིས་སྦྱར་མ།
%
\SamChe%缺省字體爲大SambhotaDege
%封面頁
\null\vfil%控制上下居中
\setboxwidth{23cm} %标题框宽度
\setboxheight{3.5cm} %标题框高度
\vskip-.4cm
\vbox{ %
  \hbox{\kern.6cm %kern参数控制居中
    \vbox{\quadrabox{\hbox{\SamChe ༄༅།།  བླ་མ་མགོན་པོ་དབྱེར་མེད་བར་དོའི་འཕྲེང་གྲོལ་བཞུགས་སོ།།}}}}
}
\vfil\null%控制上下居中
\eject%分頁
%第二頁
\def\hdr_up{\vskip4.5pt}
\def\pre_phdr{\SamAu འཕྲེང}%頁碼前的頁眉
\def\post_phdr{\SamAu གྲོལ}%頁碼後的頁眉
\pagehdrtrue %放頁眉頁碼
\setboxwidth{25.4cm} \setboxheight{6.1cm} %
\hbox{\kern-3.5pc\kern.9cm %kern参数控制居中
  \vbox to 0pt{%
    \vskip-.83cm %
    \quadrabox{\null} %
    \vss}}\nointerlineskip%
\vskip.73cm %控制第一行文字的位置正好在框內
\leftskip=3.7cm\rightskip=3.7cm %控制文字的左右邊距
\header\kern.1em བླ་མ་མགོན་པོ་དབྱེར་མེད་ལ།། བདག་ནི་གུས་པས་སྐྱབས་སུ་མཆི།། བདག་སོགས་སེམས་ཅན་ཐམས་ཅད་ཀྱི།། ཉོན་མོངས་མ་ལུས་སེལ་བར་ཤོག། མགོན་པོ་བླ་མ་དབྱེར་མེད་ལ།། བདག་ནི་གུས་པས་སྐྱབས་སུ་མཆི།། བདག་སོགས་སེམས་ཅན་
\vfil\eject
%第三頁
\setboxwidth{25.4cm} \setboxheight{6.1cm} %
\hbox{\kern-3.5pc\kern.9cm%
  \vbox to 0pt{%
    \vskip-.83cm %
    \quadrabox{\null} %
    \vss}}\nointerlineskip%
\vskip.73cm
\header\kern.1em ཐམས་ཅད་ཀྱི།། བར་ཆད་མ་ལུས་སེལ་བར་ཤོག།\ss ཧོ། ཐུགས་མཆོག་ཞི་བའི་ངང་ལས་གཡོ་མེད་ཀྱང་།། མ་རུང་གདུག་ཅན་ཐམས་ཅད་འདུལ་པའི་ཕྱིར།། ཞལ་གཅིག་ཕྱག་དྲུག་འཇིགས་པའི་སྐུར་སྟོན་པ།། ཡེ་ཤེས་མགོན་པོའི་ཞབས་ལ་
\vfil\eject
%第四頁
\leftskip=0pt\rightskip=0pt\frametrue%從這一頁開始有邊框
གསོལ་བ་འདེབས།། དེ་ལྟར་སྟོན་པའི་རྣལ་འབྱོར་བདག་ཅག་གིས།། གཅིག་ཏུ་བྱང་ཆུབ་སྙིང་པོ་བསྒྲུབ་པ་ལ།། བར་ཏུ་གཅོད་པའི་མིང་ཡང་མེད་པ་དང་།། མཐུན་རྐྱེན་ཡིད་བཞིན་འགྲུབ་པར་བྱིན་གྱིས་རློབས།། རྣལ་འབྱོར་དམ་ཚིག་ལྡན་པའི་རྗེས་སུ་འབྲང་།། སྒྲུབ་ལ་བར་དུ་གཅོད་པའི་དགྲ་བགེགས་འདུལ།། བར་དོའི་འཇིགས་སྐྱོབ་དངོས་གྲུབ་རྣམ་གཉིས་སྟེར།། སྟོབས་ལྡན་ཕྱག་དྲུག་པ་ལ་ཕྱག་འཚལ་ལོ།། རེ་ས་གཞན་ན་མེད་དོ་ཐུགས་རྗེས་ཟུང་།། འཆི་ཁར་ཞལ་མཆོག་སྟོན་པར་བྱིན་གྱིས་རློབས།། འཇིགས་རུང་བར་དོའི་འཕྲེང་ལ་འགྲོ་ཙ་ན།། ཐུགས་རྗེས་གཟིགས་ཤིག་མྱུར་མཛད་ཡེ་ཤེས་མགོན།། མཆོག་དང་ཐུན་མོངས་
\eject %加有四層方框時P2,P3,P4皆要手工斷頁
%第五頁開始統一處理
\TibPageLines=5%開始自動放雲頭符，每隔2*5行放一個
\setparshape{5}{3}%設置段落行為5短+5長，不超過6*2頁
དངོས་གྲུབ་སྩལ་ཏུ་གསོལ།། བདག་ནི་ནམ་ཞིག་འཆི་བའི་དུས་ཀྱི་ཚེ།། ཐུགས་རྗེས་མྱུར་མགྱོགས་ལྡན་པའི་སྐུར་བཞེངས་ལ།། རྣམ་འཕྲུལ་དུ་མའི་མཛད་པའི་ཟློས་གར་གྱིས།། སྐྱབས་མེད་བདག་ལ་མི་འཇིགས་སྩལ་ཏུ་གསོལ།། དགེ་པའི་འཕང་པའི་ཚེ་དང་བསོད་ནམས་ཟད།།འཇིགས་རུང་བདུད་དང་གཤིན་རྗེའི་ཕོ་ཉས་ཁྲིད།། མགོན་མེད་ཉམ་ཐག་བར་དོར་འཁྱམས་པའི་ཚེ།། ཐུགས་རྗེས་གཟིགས་ཤིག་མྱུར་མཛད་ཡེ་ཤེས་མགོན།། ཟློག་མེད་ལས་རླུང་དྲགས་པོས་རྒྱབ་ནས་དེད།། ཉོན་མོངས་ཞགས་པ་ནག་པོའི་སྐེད་ནས་བཅིངས།། ཅི་བྱ་གཏོལ་མེད་བར་དོར་འཁྱམས་པའི་ཚེ།། སྐྱབས་མགོན་མཛོད་ཅིག་མྱུར་མཛད་ཐུགས་རྗེ་ཅན།། ཆ་མེད་ཡུལ་དུ་གྲོགས་མེད་གཅིག་པུར་འཁྱམས།། འཇིགས་སྐྲགས་འཁྲུལ་པའི་སྣང་བ་ཆུ་ལྟར་འཁྲུགས།། གར་སྐྱེ་གདེངས་མེད་བར་དོར་འཁྱམས་པའི་དུས།། འཇིགས་ལས་སྒྲོལ་ཅིག་མྱུར་མཛད་ཐུགས་རྗེ་ཅན།། ལས་ལས་གྲུབ་པའི་དམྱལ་བའི་སྲུང་མ་རྣམས།། འཇིགས་པའི་རྣམ་འགྱུར་སྟོན་པ་དུ་མས་སྐོར།། སྐྱབས་འཚོལ་རིག་རིག་ཕྱོགས་སུ་བལྟ་བའི་དུས།། སྐྱབས་དང་དཔུང་གཉེན་མཛོད་ཅིག་ཐུགས་རྗེ་ཅན།། མངོན་ཤེས་ཕྲ་མོས་རང་གི་སྔར་བྱས་སྡིག། ཅུང་ཟད་དྲན་པས་རང་ལ་ཡིད་ཆད་ཅིང་།། འགྱོད་པའི་མཚོན་ཆས་རང་སྲོག་གཅོད་བཞིན་བརྒྱལ།། འདི་འདྲའི་འཇིགས་ལས་སྐྱོབས་ཤིག་ཐུགས་རྗེ་ཅན།། མྱུར་མཛད་ཐུགས་རྗེ་ཆེན་པོ་ཁྱོད་ཉིད་ཀྱིས།། དུས་འདིར་བདག་ལ་ཞལ་མཆོག་སྟོན་མཛོད་ལ།། འཇིགས་པ་ལས་སྒྲོལ་འཇིགས་མེད་གནས་སུ་སྐྱོལ།། རྣམ་དག་ཞིང་དུ་རྟེན་བཟང་མཆོག་ཐོབ་ཤོག།
\ss  ༈\nb\ss བླ་མ་ཁྱོད་ཡིན་ཤེས་རྒྱུད་བྱིན་གྱིས་རློབས།། ཡི་དམ་ཁྱོད་ཡིན་དངོས་གྲུབ་མ་ལུས་སྩོལ།། མཁའ་འགྲོ་ཁྱོད་ཡིན་ཁམས་གསུམ་དབང་དུ་བསྡུས།། ཆོས་སྐྱོང་ཁྱོད་ཡིན་ལས་བཞིའི་འཕྲིན་ལས་སྒྲུབས།། འདི་དང་ཕྱི་མ་བར་དོའི་གནས་སྐབས་སུ།། མྱུར་མཛད་བླ་མ་མགོན་པོས་རྗེས་བཟུང་ནས།། ཕྱི་ནང་གསང་བའི་བར་ཆད་ཀུན་ཞི་ཞིང་།། དོན་གཉིས་ལྷུན་གྱིས་འགྲུབ་པར་མཛད་དུ་གསོལ།། དགེ་བ་འདི་ཡིས་ཚེ་རབ་ཀུན་ཏུ་བདག། རྒྱལ་བའི་དམ་ཆོས་མ་ལུས་འཛིན་པ་དང་།། དེ་ཡི་འགལ་རྐྱེན་སེལ་ཞིང་མཐུན་རྐྱེན་སྒྲུབ།། མྱུར་མཛད་མགོན་པོ་དབྱེར་མེད་འགྲུབ་གྱུར་ཅིག།  
\SamAu ཅེས་པ་འདི་ནི་བཙུན་པ་བློ་བཟང་ཆོས་ཀྱི་རྒྱལ་མཚན་གྱིས་སྦྱར་བའོ།།    ཚེ་གླིང་ཡོངས་འཛིན་རིན་པོ་ཆེའི་གསུང་འབུམ་མ་བའི་ནང་དུ་བཞུགས་སོ།། 
\Green{ཡི་གེ་འདི་ནི་གངས་རྒྱན་མེ་ཏོག་ཅེས་པའམ། ཡང་ན་\romanfittib{\TibeX}ཞེས་པ་དང་། རྒྱ་མིང་དུ་}{\font\HzSong="SimHei" at 16pt \Red{\lower-3ex\hbox{\HzSong 雪蓮}}}\Green{ཞེས་པའི་མཉེན་ཆས་ལ་བརྟེན་ནས་བཀོད་བསྒྲིགས་བྱས་པའོ། །}\hfil
\totalpages=8%告訴TibeX一共有多少頁，在最後一個奇數頁眉加བྱོན།
\bye
```