# Printing multiple non-standard sized document pages on two sides of one piece of paper

Tags: xetex, printing

[image: Visual description]

[I am trying to find a way to create traditional Tibetan manuscripts in XeLaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183996/beginner-needing-help-to-create-simple-documentclass-for-traditional-printed-tib)(referred to as a *pecha*) and one of the things I need to do is to be able to place multiple pecha pages on one sheet of paper.

I have tried to illustrate my needs in the attached image. As you might see, there are three different LaTeX environments:

1. Pecha page number 1 with the red frames. This is a title page with a small text frame for just the title.
2. Pecha page 2 and 4 are ordinary front side pages, with a big text frame.
3. Pecha page 3 and 5 are ordinary back side pages, with an even bigger text frame.

The big green numbers represent the front side of a sheet of paper (1) and the back side (2).

For the following pages 6 to the end of the manuscript, should contain three ordinary pecha pages on one sheet of paper, just like the example image without the title page and empty backside.

I am quite new to (Xe)(La)TeX and I know that there are many bad ways of doing things, so I ask for advice on how to do this properly in XeLaTeX. I need to be able to make the configuration modular enough to follow a common rule like I have explained above, but still be able to arbitrarily insert any other environments I might want to use.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 1,3,5 on the front and 6,4,2 on the back?  (so that 1 is opposite 2, etc.)  Assume you label 3 as 2, etc.

Comment: Anyway, you can't rearrange the frame order with flowfram.  You might be able to do it in two stages using pdfpages.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that difficult, since A4 is 21cm by 27.9cm which is precisely the right size.  The document pecha.pdf was generated similar to [Beginner needing help to create simple documentclass for traditional printed Tibetan manuscripts (Pecha)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183996/beginner-needing-help-to-create-simple-documentclass-for-traditional-printed-tib?noredirect=1#comment429677_183996)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},nup=1x3,noautoscale=true]{pecha}
\includepdf[pages={6,4,2},nup=1x3,noautoscale=true]{pecha}
\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]

---

[image: page 2]

Comment: This is really exciting, but how do I do this if I have have an unknown number of pages, or if I have 100+ pages? It would be tedious to manually set the pages={}. Also, I got a strange result from using this exact latex code: http://imgur.com/IcZKK9Y - I used this to render my pdf: http://bpaste.net/show/3bUcONECtcIoD2bLvigz/