# How to make side label

Tags: fancyhdr, sidenotes

How to make and control a side label similar like this? This example i made with code:

```
\multirow{1}{*}{\begin{sideways} {\small This is my very very very veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryvery long message} \end{sideways}}
```

My method is ugly hack and works only for one page. And i want to control it similar like fancyhdr (example: turn on after title, and turn off in listoftables/listoffigures at the end)

[image: Example image]

Comment: Maybe this doesn't solves your question but it could be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin

Comment: You can specify a range of pages using flowfram.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183996/beginner-needing-help-to-create-simple-documentclass-for-traditional-printed-tib?noredirect=1#comment429677_183996 for a somewhat extreme example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for this. For example, you can use [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place content on the page arbitrarily. Below I've built an interface that places content on the left side of the page as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\fancypagestyle{sidelabel}{% Not really needed
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{--\thepage--}
  }
\providecommand{\sidelabeltext}{}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{% Place this content on the ForeGround of every page
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr-.5\textwidth-\sidelabelsep}%
    \rotatebox{90}{%
      \makebox[0pt]{%
        \sidelabeltext%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newlength{\sidelabelsep}
\setlength{\sidelabelsep}{\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\setsidelabeltext}[1]{\renewcommand{\sidelabeltext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsidelabelsep}[1]{\setlength{\sidelabelsep}{#1}}
\pagestyle{sidelabel}
\begin{document}
\setsidelabeltext{This is some side text}
\lipsum[1-6]
\setsidelabeltext{This is some very very very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very very very very very very very long side text}%
\setsidelabelsep{0.5in}
\lipsum[1-6]
\setsidelabeltext{}
\lipsum[1-6]
\setsidelabeltext{This is some side text}%
\setsidelabelsep{20pt}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

`\setsidelabeltext{<stuff>}` updates what is printed on the left of the page, while `\setsidelabelsep{<len>}` updates the length that `<stuff>` is printed from the text. Default is `\marginparsep`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with `fancyhdr`. With `\setsideheader` you tell what text should be printed from the point on.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no rule
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[L]{\printcurrentsideheader}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\newcommand\setsideheader[1]{\gdef\currentsideheader{#1}}

\newcommand{\printcurrentsideheader}{%
  \hspace*{-3em}%
  \smash{%
    \rotatebox[origin=Br]{90}{%
      \makebox[\textheight]{\currentsideheader}\hspace{\headsep}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A title}
\setsideheader{Some long text that goes in the side margin}

\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{A title}
\setsideheader{Some long text that goes in the side margin for chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-20]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]