# How to make a new page style?

Tags: formatting, text

I'm trying to do a page layout to the principle of the golden ratio, so I need to have total control over all things on the paper.

Purple lines in the picture there are margins, green lines are the dimensions (`X1`, `X2`, `Y1`, `Y2` are from the edges of the paper; `X'1`, `X'2`, `Y'1`, `Y'2` are from the top or left margin), and the red lines are to help aid visually.

How can I divide a sheet of paper into separate areas in specific locations?

For example, I want the title area to be 26.5mm from the top edge of the page, such that when text is inserted there, no matter what size and type of font used, I always have 26.5mm from the edge of ascender line text and bottom edge of the page. Next I want make second area with:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

and I want 43mm from the lower edge of the frame and edge of the page.

(Note that these dimensions – 43mm, 26.5mm – are just for example.)

Dimensions can also be from the margins (like on picture `X'1`, `Y'1`...). And so on.

Please help me achieve this, as simply as possible:

How can I **put an area on the page in a particular place** and insert whatever I want in it, such that, even if I changed the parameters of the font or image, the area will always remain in place?

`table` `minipage` or some kind of the `boxes`? or something else?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to use LaTeX for that? Sounds more like task for InDesign or something.

Comment: Is it for a multipgae document or only one page?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you, I must chcek this program.

Comment: @Bernard only one page

Comment: If it is just one page, you can do it with LaTeX. Have a look at `eso-pic`  and `textpos`.

Comment: There's also the `placeat` package, but it's in version `0.1`.

Comment: The `memoir` class provides a set of commands to do what you want. See chapter 2 *Laying out the page* in the manual `texdoc memman`.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example. Anything suggested is likely to fall afoul of your existing configuration without one.

Comment: TikZ can obviously do this, with `tikzpagenodes` for additional convenience, but may or may not be overkill.

Comment: There is also the flowfram package.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183996/beginner-needing-help-to-create-simple-documentclass-for-traditional-printed-tib/184487?s=10|0.0249#184487 for example.

Comment: @cfr I do not want to suggest wrong answers.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Some of the dimensions are measured from the margins, rather than from the paper edges.